# HTML Submit Button Branching

Tags: php, html, submit

On a series of web forms users needs to be able to move forwards and backwards. However I want to process the form irrespective of which direction they are going.

The buttonshave name of "submit" and values of "back" and next". How do I interpret the value?
This doesn't work :-)

```
if(isset($_POST[$submit['back']])) { header('location: ../pages/create_page1.php'); } 
if(isset($_POST[$submit['next']])) { header('location: ../pages/create_page3.php'); }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$submit['back']`? What is the HTML for the submit buttons?

Comment: <input type="image" name="submit" src="../images/arrows/back_50.png" width="121" height="50" border="0" value="back" />

Comment: <input type="image" name="submit" src="../images/arrows/next_50.png" width="121" height="50" border="0" value="next" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the name of the field is called `submit`, so you need to check if the field has been submitted and what its value is:

```
 if ( isset($_POST['submit]') && $_POST[submit] == 'back' )
```

However you aren't using submit buttons, you are using server side image maps, so the value might not have been submitted (depending on the browser).

Instead you need to give the fields different names, and then check to see if co-ordinates were sent for those fields.

```
<input type="image" name="submit_back" src="../images/arrows/back_50.png" width="121" height="50" border="0" alt="Back" />

 if ( isset($_POST['submit_back_x']) )
```

Comment: Yes - that works and your logic is spot on. I'm using a line now like <input type="image" name="submit_back" src="../images/arrows/back_50.png" width="121" height="50" border="0" value="back" /> and if(isset($_POST['submit_back_x'])) { header('location: ../pages/create_page1.php'); } 
  if(isset($_POST['submit_next_x'])) { header('location: ../pages/create_page3.php'); } and it works perefectly - many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the button value with `$submit`, it should be `$_POST['submit']`. 
You can try this script.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['next'])) {
    $submit = 'Next button was clicked.';
    // header(...);
} elseif(isset($_POST['back'])) {
    $submit = 'Back button was clicked.';
    // header(...);
} else {
    $submit = '';
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Click...</p>
    <input type="submit" name="back" value="Back"/>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next"/>
</form>

<br/><?=$submit;?>
```

Or with same button name and arrows like on your comments:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'next') {
    $submit = 'Next button was clicked.';
    // header(...);
} elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'back') {
    $submit = 'Back button was clicked.';
    // header(...);
} else {
    $submit = '';
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Click...</p>
    <input type="image" name="submit" src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/brightmix/128/monotone_arrow_left_small.png" value="back"/>
    <input type="image" name="submit" src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/brightmix/128/monotone_arrow_right.png" value="next"/>

</form>

<br/><?=$submit;?>
```

Comment: This part seems to make the script hang - no error messages - just hangs - if(isset($_POST['submit']) == 'next')

Comment: This works but I lose the image of the button - <input type="submit" name="submit" src="../images/arrows/next_50.png" value="next" />

Comment: You can't use `src` attribute for button with `type="submit"`. But in your first comment above you pasted a code with `type="image"`, then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jquery:

```
$('#some_button').click(funnction(){
    var $Data = $('#some-data-input').val(); 
    if($Data.length > 0){ // or some else
        window.location.href = "../pages/create_page3.php";
    } else {
       // other action
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this javascript function...

```
<script language=javascript>
function redirect()
{   
 if(document.value=="Next")
    {
            document.form.action="next.php";
    }
    else if(document.value=="Back")
    {
            document.form.action="back.php";
    }
    return true;
} 
</script>

<form method="post" name=form onsubmit='return redirect();'>
    <p>Click...</p>
    <input type="submit" name="back" value="Back"/>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Many thanks - I knew your code would work but I wnated to do it via the PHP if possible.